# Display specific widget on flutter in debug mode

Tags: android, ios, flutter, visual-studio-code

Is it possible to display a specific widget or a screen on a device or an emulator on debug mode without passing through previous screens in flutter ? 
for instance as a simple example, moving directly to a timeline screen without passing through the login/register screen ?

Comment: you can use hot reload option after going to that page for every changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `kReleaseMode` constant to do such thing:

```dart
MaterialApp(
  initialRoute: kReleaseMode == false ? '/some-dev-route' : '/',
)
```